# Binding two comboboxes to one function

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having trouble with binding to functions. Using Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path, I want it so when both comboxboxes choose a letter, it will print out the result, but am not sure how to go about this. When I try to run it, it displays the error "shortestPath() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)".

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import heapq

# GUI of the program.
class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.fill_Combo()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def fill_Combo(self):
        self.combo1= ttk.Combobox(self.root,height=5, width=20)
        self.combo1['values'] = ('a','b','w','x','y','z')
        self.combo1.current(0)
        self.combo1.place(x=5, y = 75)
        self.combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.shortestPath)

        self.combo2= ttk.Combobox(self.root,height=5, width=20)
        self.combo2['values'] = ('a','b','w','x','y','z')
        self.combo2.current(0)
        self.combo2.place(x=5, y=100)
        self.combo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.shortestPath)

    # Dijkstra's algorithm function.
    def shortestPath(start, end):
        queue,seen = [(0, start, [])], set()
        while True:
            (cost, v, path) = heapq.heappop(queue)
            if v not in seen:
                path = path + [v]
                seen.add(v)
                if v == end:
                    return cost, path
                for (next, c) in graph[v].iteritems():
                     heapq.heappush(queue, (cost + c, next, path))

                graph = {
                    'a': {'w': 16, 'x': 9, 'y': 11},
                    'b': {'w': 11, 'z': 8},
                    'w': {'a': 16, 'b': 11, 'y': 4},
                    'x': {'a': 9, 'y': 12, 'z': 17},
                    'y': {'a': 11, 'w': 4, 'x': 12, 'z': 13},
                    'z': {'b': 8, 'x': 17, 'y': 13},
               }

    cost, path = shortestPath(x, y)
    print cost, path

app()
```

Comment: that's because bind is intended for binding an event handler, not a generic function. the event handler receives a TkInter event, you're sending it to your function that takes two parameters and does no event handling

Comment: Have a look at this for [events and bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) you will also need to get `start` and `end` inside the function instead of being a parameter. And then check `if start and end` run code

Comment: Thanks I will work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Revised to reflect the not insignificant changes you made to the code in your question and to be much more object-oriented.)*

Actually, the code currently in your question raises a `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` on the `cost, path = shortest_path(x, y)` statement, and only after fixing that would it raise something like the `shortestPath() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` you mention.

The problem is you need to define a proper `Tkinter` event handler function, which are defined to normally only receive one argument (in addition to `self` if it happens to be a class method), namely the `event` which triggered them.

So in this case that's the cause of the error: `shortestPath()` expects an `x` and `y` value to be passed to it but it's only receiving one — the `"<<ComboboxSelected>>"` event from `Tkinter`.

Here's what I mean:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import heapq

# Program GUI
class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.graph = {
            'a': {'w': 16, 'x': 9, 'y': 11},
            'b': {'w': 11, 'z': 8},
            'w': {'a': 16, 'b': 11, 'y': 4},
            'x': {'a': 9, 'y': 12, 'z': 17},
            'y': {'a': 11, 'w': 4, 'x': 12, 'z': 13},
            'z': {'b': 8, 'x': 17, 'y': 13},
        }
        self.termini = {}  # storage for node ids of each terminus
        self.create_gui_widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def create_gui_widgets(self):
        values = tuple(self.graph.keys())  # valid node ids
        self.combo1 = self.create_combobox('start', values, 5, 75, 5, 20)
        self.combo2 = self.create_combobox('end', values, 5, 100, 5, 20)

    def create_combobox(self, terminus, values, x, y, height, width):
        " Utility to create ComboBox of node ids for a terminus of route. "
        combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.root, height=height, width=width)
        combobox['values'] = values
        combobox.terminus = terminus
        combobox.current(0)
        self.termini[combobox.terminus] = combobox.get()  # set to current value
        combobox.place(x=x, y=y)
        combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.combobox_event_handler)
        return combobox

    def combobox_event_handler(self, event):
        " Event handler for both ComboBoxes. "
        combobox = event.widget  # ComboBox triggering event
        self.termini[combobox.terminus] = combobox.get()  # set selected node id

        # if both a start and end terminus are defined and different, then
        # find and display shortest path between them
        start, end = self.termini.get('start'), self.termini.get('end')
        if start and end and start != end:
            cost, path = self.shortest_path(start, end)
            print('cost: {}, path: {}'.format(cost, path))

    # Dijkstra's search algorithm
    def shortest_path(self, start, end):
        graph = self.graph  # copy to local var for faster access
        queue, seen = [(0, start, [])], set()
        while True:
            cost, v, path = heapq.heappop(queue)
            if v not in seen:
                path = path + [v]
                seen.add(v)
                if v == end:
                    return cost, path
                for next, c in graph[v].iteritems():
                     heapq.heappush(queue, (cost + c, next, path))

App()
```

Comment: Thanks Martineau. That was really helpful.  I didnt know that you could've of done like this.

Comment: Since the OP is using objects, there's no reason to pass information into the function. The function can fetch the information that it needs. You've removed the object-oriented nature of the program, which is a step backwards IMO.

Comment: @Bryan: I was revising the answer somewhat in that regard (after rereading the material I linked to). However what you say is only partially true. An extra argument still needs to be passed the the common event handler in order to minimize its reference to global variables. I suppose you could tack some more attributes onto the `ComboBox` widgets, but that could get messy.

Comment: @Bryan: Revised again...to now be even more object-oriented which avoided needing to pass any additional arguments to the event handler callback (by attaching the data to the `App` object that now exists in the OP's revised question). Thanks for rebuking my too hastily-written original answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your function needs two arguments, which is true. The reason one is getting passed in is simply because that's how bindings work. In tkinter, when you create a binding and the binding fires, the function always gets an argument which is an object that contains information about the event.

The solution is simple: write a new function for your comboboxes that accepts the event, gathers the information it needs, and then does the calculation. You don't need to actually *use* the event object, but you need to accept it.

Your choice of using an object-oriented architecture makes this very easy to implement:

```
self.combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.on_combobox)
self.combo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.on_combobox)
...
def on_combobox(self, event):
    start = self.combo1.get()
    end = self.combo2.get()
    self.shortestPath(start, end)
```

Note that this solution assumes that `shortestPath` is a method on the object. You've indented it like it is, but it isn't defined to take the `self` parameter. You should give it the `self` parameter if you want to call it as an object method:

```
def shortestPath(self, start, end):
    ...
```

There are a few other problems with the code as posted, but they are unrelated to the question that was asked. I would like to offer one other piece of advice though: avoid the use of `place`. It makes your GUIs harder to write and maintain than when using `pack` or `grid`, and using `place` makes your GUI less tolerant of differences between systems. For example, on my machine the comboboxes were chopped off because the coordinates you calculated aren't right for my machine. You typically won't have those problems with `grid` and `pack`.

Comment: Im pretty new to python and thanks for the advice. Instead of using pack and grid, what do you recommend to learn more of.

Comment: @wallace: you misunderstand what I wrote. You _should_ use `pack` and `grid`.