# Dijkstra's Algorithm - wrong order of nodes in shortest path

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

I've been working on a school assignment, where I need to implement Dijkstra's algorithm. That wouldn't be too hard by itself but unfortunately, the automatic checking script disagrees with all of my implementations (I actually made like 8 different versions). All the initial data checking works correctly, only when the script generates random data, it differs. My path and script's path has the same distance, but different vertexes on the path. For example:

> Teachers path: City2, City15, City16, City6,
>
> Students path: City2, City15, City18, City0, City6,

I even contacted the teacher who just responded with "You have to use priority queue :-)" despite me using one (in fact, several implementations of one, from my own to heapq). Am I doing something wrong or is it the teacher script that's incorrect? I hope the code is self-commenting enough to be understandable. Thank you for any advice you can give me.

The algorithm is called on source vertex and computes shortest distance and path to every other connected node. If the vertex has same minDistance (ie. priority) as some that's already there, it should go in front of it, not after it.

```
class Node:
    """Basic node of the priority queue"""
    def __init__(self, data, priority):
        self.data = data
        self.nextNode = None
        self.priority = priority
        self.id = data.id

class PriorityQueue:
    """Basic priority queue with add, remove and update methods"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.count = 0

    def add(self, data, priority):
        """Adds data with priority in the proper place"""
        node = Node(data, priority)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        elif node.priority <= self.head.priority:
            node.nextNode = self.head
            self.head = node
        else:
            checker = self.head
            while True:
                if not checker.nextNode or node.priority >= checker.nextNode.priority:
                    break
                checker = checker.nextNode
            node.nextNode = checker.nextNode
            checker.nextNode = node
        return 0

    def remove(self, data):
        """Removes specified node and reconnects the remaining nodes, does nothing if node not found"""
        checker = self.head
        if not self.head:
            return 0
        if checker.id == data.id:
            self.head = checker.nextNode
        while True:
            checker = checker.nextNode
            if not checker or not checker.nextNode:
                return 0
            if checker.nextNode.id == data.id:
                checker.nextNode = checker.nextNode.nextNode
                break
        return 0

    def update(self, data):
        """Updates priority of existing node via removing and re-adding it"""
        self.remove(data)
        self.add(data, data.minDistance)
        return 0

    def getMin(self):
        """Returns the minimum priority data"""
        min = self.head
        return min.data

class Edge:
    """Edge of the graph, contains source, target and weight of line"""
    def __init__(self, source, target, weight):
        self.source = source
        self.target = target
        self.weight = weight

class Vertex:
    """Vertex of the graph, everything except id and name is filled later"""
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.minDistance = float('inf')
        self.previousVertex = None
        self.edges = []
        self.visited = False

class Dijkstra:
    """Dijkstra's algorithm implementation"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertexes = []
        self.nodes = {}
        self.unvisited = PriorityQueue()

    def createGraph(self, vertexes, edgesToVertexes):
        """Connects edges to appropriate vertexes, adds vertexes to node dictionary"""
        self.vertexes = vertexes
        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            for edge in edgesToVertexes:
                if vertex.id == edge.source:
                    vertex.edges.append(edge)
                    edgesToVertexes.remove(edge)
            self.nodes[vertex.id] = vertex
        return 0

    def getVertexes(self):
        """Returns vertexes in graph, should be called after creating it just to check"""
        return self.vertexes

    def computePath(self, sourceId):
        """Fills in minDistance and previousVertex of all nodes from source"""
        mainNode = self.nodes[sourceId]
        mainNode.minDistance = 0
        self.unvisited.add(mainNode, 0)

        while self.unvisited.head:
            mainNode = self.unvisited.getMin()
            mainNode.visited=True
            for edge in mainNode.edges:
                tempDistance = mainNode.minDistance + edge.weight
                targetNode = self.nodes[edge.target]
                self.unvisited.remove(mainNode)
                if tempDistance < targetNode.minDistance:
                    targetNode.minDistance = tempDistance
                    targetNode.previousVertex = mainNode
                    self.unvisited.update(targetNode)
        return 0

    def getShortestPathTo(self, targetId):
        """Returns list of shortest parth to targetId from source. Call only after doing ComputePath"""
        path = []
        mainNode = self.nodes[targetId]
        while True:
            path.append(mainNode)
            mainNode = mainNode.previousVertex
            if not mainNode:
                break
        return list(reversed(path))

    def resetDijkstra(self):
        """Resets ComputePath but leaves graph untouched"""
        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            vertex.minDistance = float('inf')
            vertex.previousVertex = None
        return 0
```

Comment: If "My path and script's path has the same distance, but different vertexes on the path" and both are valid paths, then it sounds like either would be a correct answer and the one returned would depend on the implementation. The problem may be the script checking the results doesn't consider that possiblility.

Comment: That's what I believe, but the teacher says that the script is different only without Priority queue implementation. I think my priority queue works correctly, so the problem indeed is in the script checker but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps the "shortest path" has been defined as the one that visits the fewest cities as well as the fewest miles traveled. There's another implement of Dijkstra's search algorithm in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34149209/355230) you could try using which is based on `heapq` rather than your home-grown `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: For some random data, my path actually uses fewer nodes than the teacher's and the length is still the same. I've actually used heapq implementation as well as some other ways, from all sources over the internet (including Stack itself of course) but always ended up with the same problem so I'm just wondering if there's some mistake in my algorithm process or something I'm overlooking

Comment: You code, however it's implemented, either finds a shortest path or it doesn't, so unless this issue has something to do with which one it selects in the case of ties, it sounds to me like you've done all you can at this point. The definition of a shortest path probably implies that the nodes are listed in the order they are to be traversed.

Comment: That's exactly the issue, the order of selection in case of ties. The teacher says the problem happens only when not using priority queue but I think it's just wrong script, if there's not some kind of problem with my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def createGraph(self, vertexes, edgesToVertexes):
>     """Connects edges to appropriate vertexes, adds vertexes to node dictionary"""
>     self.vertexes = vertexes
>     for vertex in self.vertexes:
>         for edge in edgesToVertexes:
>             if vertex.id == edge.source:
>                 vertex.edges.append(edge)
>                 edgesToVertexes.remove(edge)
>         self.nodes[vertex.id] = vertex
>     return 0
> ```

I belive this was wrong => edgesToVertexes.remove(edge)

I had similar home work and used some of your code and this one line was incorrect I think. It removed one path from vortex in every loop.